# PHP - using fpassthru to send image to mobille over imagePNG

Tags: php, android, iphone, image

I have a php script that I use to send images to mobile devices on request. In the current version the script runs and before the end I use imagePNG() to output the image to the device but in doing some reading in the examples in the php manual online I saw this example:

```
<?php
 header("Content-Type: image/png");

 # Generate cachefile for image, if it doesn't exist
 if( !file_exists($cachefile) ) {
   $im = generateimage();     # some code generates an image resource
   imagepng($im, $cachefile); # store the image to cachefile

   # don't output it like this:
   /* imagepng($im);*/

   imagedestroy($im);
 }

 $fp = fopen($cachefile, 'rb'); # stream the image directly from the cachefile
 fpassthru($fp);
 exit;
?>
```

I used this example with some modifications to send my images to mobile and it works fine but I have some questions Id like to ask:
1) is this more efficient than creating an image from the file and sending using imagePNG?

2) Also shouldnt I close the file right after using fpassthru?

3) If I do use fopen does that mean that the file is locked meaning no other devices but that one would be able to access it for that moment its being streamed?

Any opinions on the matter would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that caching the generated image is a good idea if you have a busy site.  It will certainly save memory and CPU cycles in exchange for some hard drive space.

In regards to closing the file after using `fpassthru`, it is unnecessary as PHP will close the file when the script terminates.  Since the very next line calls `exit`, there is no need to explicitly close the file.  If there was more going on after outputting the image, I would recommend closing the file when no longer in use.

As for your third question, since you have not called [flock](http://php.net/flock), the file is not locked.  If one process has it open for reading, another can open it for reading at the same time.

Just a final note, you could use the function [readfile](http://php.net/readfile) to output the file.  This saves you having to call `fopen`, but internally, `readfile` and `fpassthru` call the same PHP function `php_stream_passthru` so there is little to no difference in time or efficiency based on which one you use.

Comment: Very cool :) thanks for confirming my thoughts on using fclose I just wasnt sure and I couldnt find any documentation on the matter. So if I have files on the server, using readfile is going to save me a step of having to open the file with fopen? So then it might be even a hair more efficient to just use readfile right? I havent tried it so I dont know but would readfile stream the image to the mobile device.

Comment: There is small mention about freeing resources [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php).  I remember something more concrete a long time back, but it could have been related to mysql connections where the same rule applies.  Readfile does the same as `fpassthru` except readfile doesn't require a handle to the file (saving you that step), PHP will open it internally and write the data to the output buffer the same way that `fpassthru` does.  As mentioned before, internally they both call the same function so they behave identically.